# Using an object to fill a leaflet popup?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to change my popup name while using the leaflet GPX plugin from the GPX file name to a naming scheme object I created.

I have created an object with the file name and a descriptive name like this:

```
 gpxNamingScheme = {
        'lexBowling.gpx': 'Lexington to Bowling Green',
        'bowlinCheahaGPX.gpx': 'Bowling Green to Cheaha State Park',
        'cheahaDestin.gpx': 'Cheaha State Park to Destin',
        'destinNOLA.gpx': 'Destin to New Orleans',
        'nolaDallas.gpx': 'New Orleans to Hickory Creek State Park, Dallas',
        'dallasCapulin.gpx': 'Dallas to Capualin Volcano'}
```

I then try to add it using this function from the GPX Plugin

```
.on('addpoint', function(e) {
            if (e.point_type === 'start') {
                // console.log(gpxNamingScheme[e.target._info.name]);
                // var gpx = e.target.gpx
                //console.log(gpx);
                var name, textTitle,text;
                var text = e.target._info.name

                text = gpxNamingScheme;

                console.log(text);

                text += '<br/>Route Length: ' + (e.target._info.length/1000).toFixed(1) + ' km';
                text += '<br/>Elevation Gain: ' + e.target._info.elevation.gain.toFixed(2) + ' m';

                e.point.bindPopup(text, {offset: [0, -25]});

            }
            else if (e.point_type === 'end'){
                map.removeLayer(e.point);
            }
        })


            .addTo(map);
```

So when console.log(text) is running it gets the objects, but the "text" variable in the popup just populates with "object Object"

Comment: This will happen When you are trying to print out an object or array.
So try to check your data type before sending it.

Comment: so how would I get it to print the second value of the object based on which marker you click?

Comment: use sth like dot notation or data[key] or Object.keys(data) or Object.values(data)

Comment: what would the second part of the object gpxNamingScheme be called? Or can I specify like with a column or something?